# Unexpected results with SELECT INTO

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table valued function created in MSSQL that takes in 2 paramateres
1. End Date
2. Number of weeks to go back
to generate a table of dates with the week start date.

The PERIOD table simply is a table with 1 column (called pPeriod) with all the dates between '19971229' and '20201231'

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_Week_Rank]
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PERIOD_END DATETIME,
    @NUM_WEEKS INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT A.PPERIOD TY_PPERIOD, B.PPERIOD TY_PWKSTART, DATEADD(YY, -1, A.PPERIOD) LY_PPERIOD, DATEADD(YY, -1, B.PPERIOD) LY_PWKSTART, B.CRNK WEEK_RANK  FROM (
        SELECT PPERIOD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PPERIOD) CRNK FROM PERIODS
            WHERE PPERIOD BETWEEN DATEADD(WW, @NUM_WEEKS - 1, @PERIOD_END)  + 1 AND @PERIOD_END
        ) AS A
        JOIN (
            SELECT PPERIOD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CRNK % 7) CRNK FROM (
                SELECT PPERIOD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PPERIOD) CRNK FROM PERIODS
                    WHERE PPERIOD BETWEEN DATEADD(WW, @NUM_WEEKS, @PERIOD_END)  +  1 AND @PERIOD_END
                ) AS A
                WHERE CRNK % 7 = 1
            ) AS B ON (A.CRNK - 1)/7 = B.CRNK
)
```

I noticed then when @NUM_WEEKS is between -1 and -130, the results are correct when running this query:

```
SELECT * INTO #WEEKS FROM GET_WEEK_RANK('20160401', -104)
SELECT * FROM #WEEKS ORDER BY 1
```

However, any number below -130 (eg -156, -208), the returned results are all wrong.

[Wrong results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqZ8n.png)

You can see that TY_PWKSTART is all jumbled up and not in sync with TY_PPERIOD.
If I run the query directly, the results return fine:

```
SELECT * FROM GET_WEEK_RANK('20160401', -140)
```

What could be the issue? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

**EDIT: Posting images of results**
As you can see, both queries essentially do the same thing, but the results returned are different. The order of pWkStart in the first query when using SELECT INTO is wrong.

Wrong results:

```
SELECT * INTO #WEEK_WRONG FROM GET_WEEK_RANK('20160410', -140)
SELECT * FROM #WEEK_WRONG ORDER BY 1
```

[image: WRONG RESULTS]

Correct results:

```
CREATE TABLE #WEEK_CORRECT (TY_PPERIOD DATETIME, TY_PWKSTART DATETIME, LY_PPERIOD DATETIME, LY_PWKTART DATETIME, WEEK_RANK INT)
INSERT INTO #WEEK_CORRECT
SELECT * FROM GET_WEEK_RANK('20160410', -140)
SELECT * FROM #WEEK_CORRECT ORDER BY 1
```

[image: CORRECT RESULTS]

**EDIT2:**
Turns out that my initial query was producing unexpected results. I've fixed my query and managed to get consistent results from SELECT INTO and INSERT INTO.
Just sharing the code here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_Week_Rank]
(   
    @PERIOD_END DATETIME,
    @NUM_WEEKS INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT A.PPERIOD TY_PPERIOD, B.PPERIOD TY_PWKSTART, DATEADD(YY, -1, A.PPERIOD) LY_PPERIOD, DATEADD(YY, -1, B.PPERIOD) LY_PWKSTART, B.CRNK + 1 WEEK_RANK  FROM (
            SELECT PPERIOD, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PPERIOD)-1)/7 CRNK FROM PERIODS
                WHERE PPERIOD BETWEEN DATEADD(WW, @NUM_WEEKS, @PERIOD_END)  + 1 AND @PERIOD_END
        ) AS A
        JOIN (
            SELECT PPERIOD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PPERIOD)-1 CRNK FROM (
                SELECT PPERIOD , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CRNK ORDER BY CRNK) CRNK FROM (
                    SELECT PPERIOD, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PPERIOD)-1)/7 CRNK FROM PERIODS
                        WHERE PPERIOD BETWEEN DATEADD(WW, @NUM_WEEKS, @PERIOD_END)  +  1 AND @PERIOD_END
                    ) AS A
                ) AS A
                WHERE CRNK = 1
            ) AS B ON A.CRNK = B.CRNK
)
```

Comment: I realized its a SELECT INTO problem. If I create the temp table and use INSERT INTO, the results are fine.

Comment: TVF, views or Select queries don't return wrong values. They *are* the same under the hood. Therefore the server version doesn't matter. You can debug your code just as you would any other SELECT statement - isolate the various parts, ensure that you get the values you expect for various inputs, extract individual selects and/or joins and test them etc.

Comment: Also, there is no problem with SELECT INTO. If selecting from a TVF returns the expected data, you'll be able to generate a new table with that data using SELECT INTO.

Comment: Why are these results wrong? What is the problem? What did you expect and what did you get? If you provided at least the schema of the PERIODS table and its contents, one could guess what the problem is. A clear problem statement would be better

Comment: `CRNK % 7` can only produce 7 distinct possible values. If there are more than 7 possible rows in the second half of your query, that `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't have enough information to *unambiguously* assign row numbers. Added to which, at the same level, you're filtering to `CRNK % 7 = 1` which means that the `ORDER BY` for the `ROW_NUMBER()` has *no* useful inputs. Those row numbers are random. Unfortunately, you're not using very expressive terminology in your query so I can't work out what you're *trying* to achieve here.

Comment: Sorry, I should have commented on my code more. Basically, I'm just generating the start date for each group of 7 days for both the period P and P - 1 year. The code doesnt seem to be the issue though. The results are wrong only when I use SELECT INTO. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided! I've added the results in the question @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: The results are only "correct" by coincidence. You have a `ROW_NUMBER()` in the second half of your query where the `ORDER BY` expression you're giving it is *always* returning the value `1`. That `ROW_NUMBER()` expression, then, can assign row numbers in *any* order. I would *guess* that you've goofed on that `ORDER BY` expression,  but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your query is broken:

```
SELECT PPERIOD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CRNK % 7) CRNK FROM (
    ...
) AS A
WHERE CRNK % 7 = 1
```

Since the where clause establishes that `CRNK % 7` is equal to `1`, the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression is free to assign row numbers in any order<sup>1</sup>. I would guess that you still would want to assign row numbers in the *order* in which `PPERIOD` or `CRNK` values work, and so the expression should instead by:

```
SELECT PPERIOD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CRNK) CRNK FROM (
    ...
) AS A
WHERE CRNK % 7 = 1
```

<sup>1</sup>Since you haven't provided enough expressions in the `ORDER BY` for row numbers to be assigned *unambiguously*, there's no guarantee on the values assigned to each row.

Comment: Thanks! Yes there appeared to be a problem with my query. I altered it and managed to get consistent results. Its funny how using INSERT INTO and SELECT INTO generated different results though, but like as you mentioned, it was only "correct" by coincidence.

Comment: @jmstoh - there are so many slight changes that you might make to a query that will cause the query optimizer to select a different execution plan. Or changes to the server or database (different data volumes, different recent transaction history, patches, etc) that would suddenly make the existing query use a different plan.